# Diameter protocol CCR request not routable

Tags: diameter-protocol

I am using the jdiameter stack from http://i1.dk/JavaDiameter/ for my diameter implementation. The initial CER request goes through fine but on sending a CCR request i get a error as "not routable". Can anyone help me out with this?.
Also I am looking to build a Diameter call charging client and have gone through mobicents, but am unable to get started on the same due to lack of basic tutorials as to how to go about it.
P.S. there is already a similar question posted some time back but that failed to resolve my query.

Answer (score 1):

"not routable" looks like more of a routing issue where a Diameter Message can’t be delivered because there is no Host with Diameter URI present in Destination-Host AVP in associated Realm.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following Mobicents Diameter example https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/DiameterRoRf ?

Comment: hi,Thanks for your response. The mobicents page is not very clear on the pre-req and how to go about building a client. Anyways got the above jar to work by tweaking the remote host-id.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got that error too, but I changed my library to JavaDiameterPeer of [Openimscore.org](http://www.openimscore.org/download); and that library worked for me. Also you need to check TCP packets through Wireshark tool. 

not routable: maybe because of invalid AVPs, vendor-ids, mandatories or something like that... Wireshark will tell you everything